# Web Designer - Google Maps Creation Process on behalf of Customer

Tags: google, customer-service, google-api

I hope I'm posting this on the right sub-site of SO. Anyway, the question is as follows. How do you guys handle the Google Maps registration process for customers? Now that Google Maps is no longer 'free' (even if using the 'standard modes' and 'within the free limits' - one still needs a Google Cloud account with an active billing profile / credit card details).

In the past, I would handle this whole shlep for my customers since they're scared the moment they have to do anything on a web site (eg: sign up for a google account and/or get an API key). However, I'm not comfortable to use the business credit card to give each of my web design customers and 'active billing profile'.

Do you:

```
1) Tell them to sack up and give them the process and they must go through it all and give you the API key?
2) Do as much of it as possible for them and tell them to do the rest (eg: add the CC to the account)?
3) Do it all yourself under your own account and just setup a new project for their domain and charge them for their usage based on the project usage?
4) Something else? (eg: a developers portal that allows me to do this on behalf of a customer without the billing info up front)
```

Comment: You are creating custom websites that each use the Google Maps API?   Maybe it is time to switch to open street maps.